# If $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)=1$, then show that $\gcd(ab \pmod {n}, n)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)=1$, then show that $\gcd(ab \pmod {n},  n)=1$

---

It is clear to me that $\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(b,n)=1 \implies \gcd(ab,n)=1$ is true by considering prime factorizations of $a,b,n$ and $ab$. However the $mod$ thing is throwing me off. Any help ? Thanks!

Comment: It makes no difference - reducing $ab \bmod n$ is essentially just subtracting some multple of $n$ from $ab$, which doesn't change the $\gcd$.

Comment: Joffan is correct. Generally $\,j\equiv k\pmod n\,\Rightarrow\,\gcd(j,n) = \gcd(k,n).\ $ Above is the special case when $\, k = (j\ {\rm mod}\ n).\ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Write $ab \bmod n = ab + kn$ for some integer $k$. Suppose that $u>0$ divides both $ab \bmod n$ and $n$. Then $u$ divides $kn$, and then divides $(ab \bmod n) - kn = ab$. You're done. Because the only positive number that divides $ab$ and $n$ is 1.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ has no prime factors in common with $n$. The same $b$. Therefore $\text{gcd}(ab,n)=1$.

It follows that, for all integers $k$, we have
$$\text{gcd}(ab+kn,n)=1$$
which is exactly your claim (indeed $ab \pmod{n}$ is a class of integers).